# 2017-10-09 AWS Cloudwatch metrics older than 63 days are missing

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

Is anyone else experiencing this? AWS Cloudwatch Metrics are supposed to be saved for 15 months. 1 minute metrics are rolled up into 5 minute metrics after 2 weeks, and 5 minute metrics are rolled up into 1 hour metrics after 2 months.

Currently, as of October 10, 2017, my AWS Cloudwatch console is not showing any metrics older than 2 months.

Comment: We're talking hourly metrics, right?

Comment: sorry, yes, only the hourly metrics are missing

Comment: A cursory glance at my own CloudWatch metrics suggests that either we are both misinterpreting something... or that you have a good point.

Answer (score 0):

- Graphed

  - metric > Period (set 1 hr)

Then you can view metrics up to 457 days then.

[image: Graphed metrics screenshot, with period set to 1 hour in the dropdown list]

Comment: i may be blind but i dont see on your picutres 457 days?